# How save the result of reasoner FaCT++ or HermiT in Protege

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege, fact++

I'm using **Protégé 4.3** and I want to save the results of the reasoner to the ontology file. When I stopped the reasoner, all results disappeared.

How can I save results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Protégé, use *File → Export inferred axioms as ontology…*

That should do what you're looking for.