# why rdf:type doesn't work with father classes?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege4

In my protege, I state explicitly that the class **Symphony** is subclass of class **Recommendable**, as illustrated here:
[Classes Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYMqT.png)

I've also added some instances to the class Symphony, when I query the Symphony instances, I get results. However, when I query the Recommendable instances, I get nothing.

This is the query for Symphony class:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?subject   WHERE {
  ?subject rdf:type owbes:Symphony
}
```

And here is the result:
[Symphony instances query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqyia.png)

This is the query for Recommendable class.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?subject   WHERE {
  ?subject rdf:type owbes:Recommendable
}
```

This result is empty, as you see here
[Recommendable instances query result][3]

Both from the same prefix. What wrong did I do?

This is what's being generated in the owl file:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="bla bla bla/recommendation-systems#Symphony">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="bla bla bla/recommendation-systems#Recommendable"/>
</owl:Class>
```

As you see, I've correctly made Symphony a subclass of Recommendable

I found the solution:
Making this query solves the problem

```
SELECT   ?subject   WHERE {
  ?subject rdf:type ?type.
  ?type rdfs:subClassOf owbes:Recommendable
}
```

Yet, I don't know why rdf:type doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/welovethesemanticweb#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/welovethesemanticweb"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:recommendation-systems="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/welovethesemanticweb"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Annotation properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#hasSimilarityValue -->

    <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#hasSimilarityValue"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#composedBy -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#composedBy">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#hasArtist"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#AsymmetricProperty"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#IrreflexiveProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Symphony"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Composer"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Composed By</rdfs:label>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#fromEra -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#fromEra">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#AsymmetricProperty"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#IrreflexiveProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Artist"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#MusicalEra"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Describes the musical era that music is from</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">From Era</rdfs:label>
        <recommendation-systems:hasSimilarityValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.1</recommendation-systems:hasSimilarityValue>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#hasArtist -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#hasArtist">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#AsymmetricProperty"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#IrreflexiveProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Recommendable"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Artist"/>
        <rdfs:comment>Describes the arties of the music</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Has Artist</rdfs:label>
        <recommendation-systems:hasSimilarityValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.4</recommendation-systems:hasSimilarityValue>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Data properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#contributeToSimilarities -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#contributeToSimilarities">
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Artist -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Artist">
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#MusicalEra"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Recommendable"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Song"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Symphony"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Composer -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Composer">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Artist"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#MusicalEra"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Recommendable"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Song"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Symphony"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#MusicalEra -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#MusicalEra">
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Recommendable"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Singer"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Song"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Symphony"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Recommendable -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Recommendable">
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Singer"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Singer -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Singer">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Artist"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Song"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Symphony"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Song -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Song">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Recommendable"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Symphony -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Symphony">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Recommendable"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Adele -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Adele">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Artist"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Singer"/>
        <recommendation-systems:fromEra rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#current"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Beethoven -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Beethoven">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Artist"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Composer"/>
        <recommendation-systems:fromEra rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#classical"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Dies_Irae -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Dies_Irae">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Recommendable"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Symphony"/>
        <recommendation-systems:composedBy rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Mozart"/>
        <recommendation-systems:hasArtist rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Mozart"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Dies Irae</rdfs:label>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Le_nozze_di_Figaro -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Le_nozze_di_Figaro">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Recommendable"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Symphony"/>
        <recommendation-systems:composedBy rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Mozart"/>
        <recommendation-systems:hasArtist rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Mozart"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Le Nozze Di Digaro</rdfs:label>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Mozart -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Mozart">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Artist"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Composer"/>
        <recommendation-systems:fromEra rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#classical"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#baroque -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#baroque">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#MusicalEra"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#classical -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#classical">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#MusicalEra"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#current -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#current">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#MusicalEra"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#romantic -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#romantic">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#MusicalEra"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#5th_Symphony -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#5th_Symphony">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Recommendable"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Symphony"/>
        <recommendation-systems:composedBy rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Beethoven"/>
        <recommendation-systems:hasArtist rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Beethoven"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">5th Symphony</rdfs:label>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Requiem:_Sequentia -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Requiem:_Sequentia">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Recommendable"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Symphony"/>
        <recommendation-systems:composedBy rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Mozart"/>
        <recommendation-systems:hasArtist rdf:resource="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Mozart"/>
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Requiem Sequentia</rdfs:label>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // General axioms
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    <rdf:Description>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#AllDifferent"/>
        <owl:distinctMembers rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#baroque"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#classical"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#romantic"/>
        </owl:distinctMembers>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 4.1.3.20151118-2017) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi -->
```

Comment: Here is the result for the Recommendable instances query result ([3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/griJp.png) I couldn't post it in the question because I don't have enough point to post more than two images

Comment: The images are not appeared because I don't have enough points. However, if you click on them, you'll see them. Thanks for help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a class C is declared as a subclass of class D, you can *infer* that an instance of C is also an instance of D.  However, that process of inference is something that you need a *reasoner* for.  If you're not using a reasoner, you won't automatically get that result.  In short, you're asking for a triple of the form

```
?subject rdf:type owbes:Recommendable
```

but that's not in the data.  What's in the data is two triples:

```
?subject rdf:type owbes:Symphony  
owbes:Symphony rdfs:subClassOf owbes:Recommendable
```

In this case, you can actually get by using a SPARQL query with property paths;  you don't need a full reasoner.  You can use a query like this:

```sql
select ?subject where {
    ?subject rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* owbes:Recommendable
}
```

This says to find subjects that have a type that's linked to owbes:Recommendable by a chain (possibly of length zero) of rdfs:subClassOf properties.  In practice, that means to find ?subjects that are owbes:Recommendable or one of its subclasses.

For some more information, see:

- [Using SPARQL for limited RDFS and OWL reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20474862/1281433)
- [how to do reasoning in Jena via Sparql Query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24136532/1281433)

Comment: Well thank you, but how can I use the reasoner? What I've done is the followings: In my protoge, I created the ontology, and then I clicked start the reasoner (and select the reasoner), then I saved (extracted) the ontology in OWL format. Then I opened fuseki and uploaded that owl file to it. May I ask you please what should I do to extract the *infered* data? or it is something in Fuseki I have to enable?

Comment: @AniaDavid Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/23079459/1281433 and https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/protege-discussion/2013-September/006718.html.

Comment: Thank you, but I still believe it's something in Fuseki, because it's a sparql end point so It should support reasoning, what do you think?

Comment: @AniaDavid **"because it's a sparql end point so It should support reasoning, what do you think?"** Not at all.  SPARQL is an *RDF query language*.  RDF is just a bunch of triples.  All a SPARQL endpoint is required to do is let you search for triples.  No reasoning required whatsoever.

Comment: @AniaDavid That said, you can *configure* Fuseki to use a reasoner, but that's a whole different issue.  The best reference for that the is the documentation.

Comment: Bty, I did as one of the links, you've sent, suggests. I generated the Ontology using File->export infered .... but the rdf:type still doesn't working with Recommendable, it just works with Symphony

Comment: @AniaDavid Without seeing your actual data, I doubt that any users here can debug the issue that you're encountering.

Comment: Okay you are saying that the reasoning feature is not a required task for a SPARQL end point. Yet, Fuseki has it. Right?

Comment: Well, i can show you the data, it's pretty simple. How would you like to show you please ?

Comment: The same way you would for any other kind of question,  edit the question and add it in.

Comment: I updated my question with the extracted data using File->export infered ... I believe there is something wrong in that data, because though my data is small, but sounds like that generated data is even smaller. could you have a look please ? I appreciate your time with me. To be honest, I changed the name of the URI in order to keep the privacy of my school. I appreciate your understanding.

Comment: Now I've made another update to the question, updating the new data I could extract. Sounds like there was an option to extract the full Ontology. I hope that will work with your machine.

Comment: Hello, now it's working. my mistake is that when I changed the URI of the Ontology in protoge, I didn't do that in the Fuseki. I'm sorry. Now it's working. I'll try to study how can I enable a reasoner on Fuseki. Thanks for your help and support. I value that a lot.

Comment: @AniaDavid If you think that this answer resolved your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  On the other hand, since this was pretty much a typographical error, you may also want to consider simply removing the question.